# Storybook with Angular Couldn't find story matching 'story-title--task-name'

Tags: storybook, angular-test, angular-storybook

I try to work with Storybook in my Angular project, and I run into a misterious error message, and I have no clue what's happening here.

This is my `tag.component.stories.ts` file:

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Meta, moduleMetadata, Story } from '@storybook/angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';
import { TagComponent } from './tag.component';

export default {
  title: 'Attached Tags',
  component: TagComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [TagComponent],
      imports: [BrowserModule, CommonModule, RouterModule, AppRoutingModule]
    })
  ]
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args) => ({
  props: {
    ...args
  }
});

export const GreenPost = Template.bind({});
GreenPost.args = {
  tag: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Test tag',
    color: '#bada55',
    type: 'Post'
  }
};
```

I get this error message:

```
Couldn't find story matching 'attached-tags--green-post'.
- Are you sure a story with that id exists?
- Please check your stories field of your main.js config.
- Also check the browser console and terminal for error messages.
```

So, I'm pretty sure after reading the documentation's "Simple component" section I don't have any idea how or where should I need to define any id for stories.

Here is my `.storybook/main.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions"
  ],
  "framework": "@storybook/angular",
  "core": {
    "builder": "webpack5"
  }
}
```

This is the factory default I think.

Also checked the browsers console, and nothing else, just the visible message twice.

Any idea how can I solve this issue?

Comment: the id is automatically created based on the title and the named export. Check that the story is in the path that is specified in the main.js. Usually this error happens when you change the story and then the url is outdated. Try navigating to other stories and back again and restarting the server.

Comment: @Danny You should write an answer, your comment helped me.